# How to use Sequelize belongsTo

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have simple sequelize models like below.

```
// user.js
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  const user = sequelize.define(
    "User",
    {
      name: {
        field: "name",
        type: DataTypes.STRING(50),
        unique: true,
        allowNull: false
      },
      uid: {
        field: "uid",
        type: DataTypes.STRING(50),
        allowNull: false
      }
    },
    {
      freezeTableName: true,

      tableName: "user"
    }
  );
  user.associate = function(models) {
    user.hasMany(models.friend, {
      foreignKey: "uid"
    });
  };

  return user;
};
```

And there is another model.

```
// friend.js 
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  const friend = sequelize.define(
    "Friend",
    {
      uid: {
        field: "uid",
        type: DataTypes.STRING(50),
        allowNull: false
      },
      jsonId: {
        field: "json-id",
        type: DataTypes.STRING(50),
        allowNull: true
      },
      nlpId: {
        field: "nlp-id",
        type: DataTypes.STRING(50),
        allowNull: true
      }
    },
    {

      freezeTableName: true,

      tableName: "friend"
    }
  );
  friend.associate = function(models) {
    friend.belongsTo(models.user, { foreignKey: "uid" });
  };

  return friend;
};
```

And there is index.js. When I run sequelize, it gives me an error like "Error: Friend.belongsTo called with something that's not a subclass of Sequelize.Model".

Could you recommend some advice for this problem? Thank you so much for reading it.

```
db.user = require('./user')(sequelize, Sequelize);
db.friend = require('./friend')(sequelize, Sequelize);
```

Comment: think that happens because you require it, because your model is not defined on first process tick when everything loads up, but when you call it using require, meaning your models are not defined yet. Try defining your model without require, just define them in some file, and hook up that files using `import './models/users'`

Answer (score 1):

Write to the user model

```
User.associate = models => {
        User.hasMany(models.Friend, {
            as: 'friends',
            foreignKey: 'userId'
        });
    };
```

Write to the friend model

```
Friend.associate = models => {
        Friend.belongsTo(models.User, {
            as: 'friend',
            foreignKey: 'userId'
        });
    };
```